# Number puzzle i really need help with

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

I found this puzzle in a VRChat world.

Its a 6 number puzzle, and I need to know the value of “? ? ? ? ? ?”.

I also need to know the number. [image]

Comment: odd numbers are changing but i still cant come up with right answer

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Where did you get this puzzle from? For puzzles you found elsewhere, we require you to link to the original source, otherwise it could be considered plagiarism.

Comment: its from a vrchat world someone create to challenge people brains i dont know if i can provide a source off a game

Comment: Hmm... fair point. In that case, I personally think an edit to the question saying "I found this puzzle in a VRChat world" would be enough.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that this is a poorly specified puzzle (as is common with these things). @MacGyver88's solution is completely valid. But you could equally say

> The last row is double the second last row and get 242424.

In fact, if you assume that this is a column-by-column operation, you could set up a system of simultaneous equations to figure out what that operation was (assuming it was linear which is not necessarily valid but we would want to start with simple assumptions):

\begin{eqnarray}
3&a &+ &b &+& c &= 2\\
2 &a &+ 2&b &+& c &= 4\\
&a &+ 3 &b &+ &c &= 6
\end{eqnarray}

This [yields](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3a%2Bb%2Bc%3D2%2C%202a%2B2b%2Bc%3D4%2C%20a%2B3b%2Bc%3D6) a family of solutions:

\begin{eqnarray}
b &=& a+2\\
c &=& -4a
\end{eqnarray}

The first solution is simply the $a=0$ case. But there are infinitely many others. [Here's a spreadsheet enumerating some of them](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wY2NYp536iFvTfDq_hYog-8LGBvvmetENQRZ2SvcEZI/edit?usp=sharing). Here's a screenshot if you don't want to fiddle with the formulae:

> [image: Number Puzzle]

The two "best" ones are the $a=0$ already mentioned and the $a=-1$ which yields:

> "Take the first number from the second and add 4" as the rule. This gives 442200 for the question marks

Answer (score 2):

So, the solution might be

> 777333

Here's how I did it

> Fold the first two lines down the middle
>  Add the numbers together
>  Enter the numbers in order from top to bottom on the last line
>  Here's what I did:
> [image]

Comment: Just a possible pattern I noticed.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

> 242424

> X1y1z1 
>  X2y2z2 
>  X3y3z3 
>  
>  X3=(x1+x2)-(x1-x2) 
>  Y3=(y1+y2)-(y1-y2) 
>  Z3=(z1+z2)-(z1-z2)

Comment: $(x_1+x_2) - (x_1-x_2) = 2 x_2$ . It just says $2\times121212 = 242424$